# Laravel create or update many in a model linked relationship from form

Tags: php, laravel, forms, relationship

I want to create/update, all records from the form, I'm searching for a clean solution that doesn't use any loops, the following can be easily fixed with a loop. I'm using laravel 5.8

Model **Class:School** -> HasMany (Model **Class:Program**)

**This is the store method** (this needs fixing)

```
public function store(Request $request, School $school)
{
    $school->programs()->createMany(array($request->day, $request->schedule));
}
```

**This is the update method** (this needs fixing)

```
public function update(Request $request, School $school)
{
    $school->programs()->update(array($request->day, $request->schedule));
}
```

The form has a simple array input

```
<td width><input type="number" name="day[]" placeholder="Course Day (1-5)" class="form-control" /></td>
<td width><input type="text" name="schedule[]" placeholder="Actual schedule" class="form-control" /></td>
```

[image]
[image]

1. How can I properly use createMany and pass an array of the
   arrays?
2. How can I properly update the above arrays?

Please try to provide a clean solution, I just created the example above to try and learn proper structuring and data management in laravel.

Comment: the database structure of the `program` table?

Comment: I'm searching for a solution for the store() and update() functions, not database :)

Comment: yes, we're gonna need to know the columns of the programs table

Comment: added the programs table for reference, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether this answer is clean enough for you, but the closest I can get is, use `map` function of collection.

```
public function store(Request $request, School $school)
{

    $school->programs()->createMany(
        collect($request->day)->map(function($day, $key) {
            return [
                'day' => $day,
                'schedule' => request('schedule')[$key],
            ];
        })->toArray()
    );
}
```

Comment: Just a quick fix for your function, you must add collect(....)->toArray() in order to process, other than that, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that each value in "day" key match with each value in "schedule" key, such as day "1" matches with schedule "test1". We might do something like this.

```
public function store(School $school)
{
    collect(request('day'))->map(function ($day, $index) {
        return [
            'day' => day,
            'schedule' => request('schedule')[$index]
        ];
    )->each(function ($program) use ($school) {
        $school->programs()->create($program);
    });
}
```

To make the code a bit cleaner, I use request() helper function instead of the $request object.